# glassfish 3.1.2 monitoring EJB container, bean-methods

Tags: methods, glassfish, ejb, javabeans, monitoring

the glassfish application server provides a nice monitoring REST interface.
To use it u can enable several monitorable items in the admin console, for example the EJB container. The documentation says, you can retreive EJB-statistics for every deployed application.

If you request a URL like **localhost:4848/monitoring/domain1/server/applications/*APPNAME/EJBNAME*** you will get statistics for a given EJB of the application.

Further, there is a possibility to look more deeply into each bean-method of the ejb, for example the **executiontime**, about which the documentation says:
*"Time, in milliseconds, spent executing the method for the last successful/unsuccessful attempt to run the operation. This is collected for stateless and stateful session beans and entity beans **if monitoring is enabled on the EJB container.**"*

The problem now is, monitoring is enabled on the EJB-container (Level set to HIGH), but nothing is sampled in any bean-method in any EJB in any deployed application.

Is there something special to do in the bean and/or the glassfish ?

Thanks in advance for help,

Chris

EDIT:

Ok, I noticed something more about that behaviour:

In the server log you get a log message for each deployed EJB like that:

```
INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB DataFetcher // ...
```

If I set the ejb-container monitoring level to HIGH (which is what I want to do), I get the following warning for each deployed EJB, regardless which app I deploy:

```
WARNING: MNTG0201:Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class : com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
```

I googled the warning but none of the resulst really help me enabling EJB monitoring...

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a Bug in Glassfish.
EJB Monitoring is currently not working in 3.1.2.
JIRA issue is already raised: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19677

Comment: Thanks, was about to raise one as well, but this is not neccessary then :)

Comment: So, the current workaround is just to disable monitoring for ejb container. Thanks for putting me on the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "special" to do.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abeea.html

For me it seems as if you probably enabled the monitoring option on the wrong configuration. Please double check.

Comment: Yep, level is set to HIGH on the corresponding configuration. I only have one configuration ("server"). Anyway it is enabled in the "default" config as well. So that should be a definitve hit configuration-wise :)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this message you can disable the monitoring on ejb container option below in the image

From `Monitor Data--->Configure monitoring--->make ejb container log off`
[image: diable monitor]

Comment: This is contrary to what the OP was asking, but anyway it helped me to *disable monitoring service* which I was looking for. To disable monitoring from the configuration file prior to starting the server (because monitoring causes the server to start extremely slowly or not to start at all). The file is {jboss-home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml. Look for the entry 'monitoring-service', and remove attributes or set them to OFF in the 'module-monitoring-levels'